# Using a barcode scanner in winRT application

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, barcode-scanner

I would like to create a new winRT (metro) application.
It is essential however that I can handle input from a barcode scanner in this application.  I've searched here and there, but until now haven't found any guidance on doing such a thing.
Or if this is even possible in a metro style application.
So:
- Is it possible?
- Maybe an example on how this can be done?

Note: for the moment it would be OK if I have a solution for USB barcode scanners only.
Others (serial, bluetooth) are nice but not essential...

Comment: Don't barcode scanners just act as keyboards, usually?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the commment, barcode scanners act as keyboards, namely if you have focus on text field and you scan something, then the text field gets feeled with the scanned number. Some barcode scanners are programmed to enter an escape character (eg carriage return) after inputing the scanned sequence, so you could monitor the text field and if you find this escape character then trigger an action, instead of waiting for the user to press enter or push a button. The barcode scanner I have been working with, had some pages with "special barcodes" in its documentation that you could print and the scan in order to program the device without to install a driver or a configuration application.

Comment: But what if you don't have a text field? You could catch key_up and key_down I guess.  But could I actually differentiate where the input actually comes from (keyboard or scanner)?

Comment: Depending on the device (the scanner) and its programming abilities, I guess you could program it to input a special character on the begining of the sequence. In that case you could monitor for this character and by this way you will know where the input is coming from .